# remove html tags from string using bs4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to make a program to read the price of bitcoin from a website.  I used bs4 and was bale to get the section I was looking for but its surrounded by the html tags.

```
   output: <div class="priceValue___11gHJ">$52,693.18</div>
```

I just want the price and i have tried the regex and lxml methods, but I keep getting errors

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#get url
url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"
r = requests.get(url)

#parse html
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

#find div
find_div = soup.find('div', {"class": "priceValue___11gHJ"})
print(find_div)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `.text`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#get url
url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"
r = requests.get(url)

#parse html
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

#find div
find_div = soup.find('div', {"class": "priceValue___11gHJ"})
print(find_div.text) # $52,693.18
```